# How do I access a modified class variable inside a function, from another file in another function in Python 3.6.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Class being modified:**

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.maxmp = 20
        self.mp = self.maxmp
        self.fireres = 0.1
        self.thunderres = 0.01
        self.totalattack = 15
        self.basedefense = 20
        self.blooddrops = 50
        self.pots = 1
        self.allmagic = ["fireball", "t-phase"]
        self.usemagic = ""
        self.armor = ["dirt rag"]
        self.curarmor = "naked"
        self.weapon = ["snapped sword"]
        self.curweapon = "fist" 
    @property
    def defense(self):
        defense = self.basedefense
        
        if self.curarmor == "naked":
            defense += 0
            self.fireres += .1
        if self.curarmor == "dirt rag":
            defense += 5
            self.fireres += .1
        if self.curarmor == "leather armor":
            defense += 10
            
        if self.curarmor == "metal armor":
            defense += 20

        return defense
        
    @property
    def attack(self):
        attack = self.totalattack
        
        if self.curweapon == "snapped sword":
            attack += 5
            
        if self.curweapon == "greatsword":
            attack += 15
            
        if self.curweapon == "sword":
            attack += 7
            
        if self.curweapon == "fist":
            attack += 0
        
        return attack
```

**File1:**

```
import sys
import os
import time
import random
from File1 import name


name()
```

1. File1 goes to File2

**File2:**

```
import sys
import os
import time
import random
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from File3 import start1
from Classes_Player import Player

def name():
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    print("Have you got a name lad!?")
    option2 = input("Type (Yes or No):").lower()
    if option2 == "yes" or option2 == "y":
        print("Ah, brilliant!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("What be it?")
        option = input("Type:")
        global PlayerIG
        PlayerIG = Player(option)
        if len(option) >= 20:
            print("shorten it a bit please, for brevity")
            time.sleep(2)
            clear()
            name()
        elif len(option) == 0:
            print("Lad that's not a name, that's emptiness")
            time.sleep(2)
            clear()
            name()
        else:
            print("Are you sure? (Yes or No)")
            ans = input().lower()
            if ans == "yes" or ans == "y":
               print("Alrighty then, just wanted to be sure lad.")
               time.sleep(2)
               start1()
```

2. What it's doing here is modifying the Player class, and making it to where the name variable of the class is the user's input (I believe). Then it goes to File3

## File3

```
import sys
import os
import time
import random
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from Intro import *


def start1():
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()
    print("Name: {}".format(PlayerIG.name))
    print("Health: {}/{}".format(PlayerIG.health, PlayerIG.maxhealth))
    print("Attack: {}".format(PlayerIG.attack))
    print("Defense: {}".format(PlayerIG.defense))
    print("Mana: {}/{}".format(PlayerIG.mp, PlayerIG.maxmp))
    print("Equipped Armor: {}".format(PlayerIG.curarmor))
    print("Equipped Weapon: {}".format(PlayerIG.curweapon))
    print("Healing potions: {}".format(PlayerIG.pots))
    print("Wealth: {}\n".format(PlayerIG.blooddrops))
    print("1.) Inventory")
    print("2.) Check Player")
    print("3.) Save")
    print("4.) Fight")
    print("5.) Shop")
    print("6.) Exit")
    ans = input().lower()
    if ans == "inventory" or ans == "i" or ans == "1":
        inventory()
    elif ans == "check player" or ans == "cp" or ans == "check" or ans == "c" or ans == "2":
        status()
    elif ans == "save" or ans == "s" or ans == "3":
        clear()
    elif ans == "exit" or ans == "e" or ans == "6":
        exit
    elif ans == "fight" or ans == "f" or ans == "4":
        prefight()
    elif ans == "shop" or ans == "s" or ans == "5":
        shop_keeper()
    else:
        start1()
```

3. I get an error here `"NameError: name 'PlayerIG' is not defined"`, I've looked it up but to no prevail on help for this instance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you haven't shown your `Files` correctly e.g. `from File1 import name` but it looks like `name` is in `File2`. You've not actually defined a global variable `PlayerIG` e.g. `PlayerIG = None` outside of any function definition. In you first file you can `from File1 import *` to bring any global variables into that files namespace. However, `global` variables are considered harmful and you may want to rethink, why not just pass it in to `start1(PlayerIG)`. You really should read the help [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AChampion     Thanks, it worked! Great advice, i'll look into it for futures sake.